# Bake modifiers (ocean) animation into keyframe

Tags: animation, modifiers

I have a plane with ocean modifier and keyframes that adjust the time. How do i bake the ocean animation for each frame so I don't need to use the modifier while exporting?

Answer (score 1):

You have to export it to mdd format, then import the mdd file on your model, which will appear as shapekeys for every frame. You have to turn on the "Import-Export: NewTek MDD format" addon.